# How to solve chrome opening old tab

Tags: google-chrome, powershell, microsoft-edge

Chrome is driving me crazy today,

I use a powershell script top open different tab for certain of our software.

But for some reaosn, chrome decide to open multiple Tab with all the different previous session for some reason and I have no idea why it's doing that.

I check my script the issue isn't from there, also check on a different computer same problem, the issue didn't happen like 1 week before.

Chrome is setup with a read only on the preference file but it still managed to ignore that parameter.

I already try to clean chrome historic, restart computer and reinstall chrome issue ISN'T SOLVED

What is the solution here ?

I can't use other web browser only chrome and edge and the issue is also on edge.

No modification hasn't been made IN my script for like 2 month

Comment: Show your script logic and change anything sensitive if applicable to some other example value instead. Then folks will know what to start for testing to try to emulate your issue and then help you see if it's some reason they find per running it on their side that they can share back with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty standard fayre for a browser these days, to re-open tabs from the last session. It's been in Safari so long I've forgotten how to live without it.

In Chrome it's in Preferences > On start-up >

[image]

Comment: I've already check that, the option is set to Open the new Tab page.